# I need a shortcut for selecting inside links in order to use this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to web development and I am in a little trouble. I am using the following jQuery function in order to scroll the page for specific divs with internal links.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top-30
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

The problem is that the function works also on other elements with internal links that should not have the scroll effect (accordion elements). The only way I can prevent this from happening is to write the same function for all the links that I want to apply the function to ("#link1", "#link2", "#link3", "#link4", ... , "#linkn").
I tried to use an array with the links and to use each value of the array in the function but I don't know how to write the loop.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you change the html? Like adding a class to the links in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a[href^="#"]')
```

This selector is saying "get all `a` tags that start with `href=#`". So the best idea would be to change this selector, to instead go by class names.

You could for example do this:

```
<a href="#link1" class="autoscrollLink">link</a>
```

And js:

```
$('.autoscrollLink').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top-30
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```